# Replace Wildcard Value in String with PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I am trying to simply remove a known string and an unknown number in a string from a string using the Powershell `replace` command and can't quite figure the syntax for a wildcard out.

My input string looks like this:

```
MyCatalog_AB_24.xml
```

However, the number is dynamic and won't always be `24`.

And I need to wind up with:

```
MyCatalog.xml
```

So, I need to remove anything between `MyCatalog` and `.xml` (essentially the `_AB_##` part).

Here's the commands I've tried:

```
$_ -replace 'MyCatalog_AB_*.xml', 'MyCatalog.xml'
$_ -replace 'MyCatalog*.xml', 'MyCatalog.xml'

set num='\d'
$_ -replace 'MyCatalog_AB_%num%.xml', 'MyCatalog.xml'
```

I know I should be using some sort of regular expression, but I have some working code that someone else wrote that does something similar by just inserting an `*` where the wildcard data is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$_ -replace 'MyCatalog_AB_\d+\.xml', 'MyCatalog.xml'`. `\d+` matches one or more digits, and `\.` matches a literal dot.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perfect! I knew it had to be something pretty simple. RegEx just isn't my thing. If you post as an answer, I'll mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$_ -replace 'MyCatalog_AB_\d+\.xml', 'MyCatalog.xml'.
```

`\d+` matches one or more digits, and `\.` matches a literal dot.